# I am a beginner and I want to know how to make a an action last a sertain time or how to end one and start loading another. C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class StartGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Load12AM()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("12AM");
    }

    IEnumerator officeLoad()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Office");
    }
}
```

I don t know how to make the code work because, it just stays on the first scene.

Comment: First of all please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Comment: And well ..  you nowhere ever use `officeLoad` so what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have written something called "officeLoad"!
If you are trying to call it, try writing it like this:

```
StartCoroutine(officeLoad());
```

The concurrent process is special, so you can't call it directly, you have to use "StartCoroutine" like I did!
(^∀^)